# Dependency Property + UserControl + ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, user-controls

Given I have this UserControl:

```
public class MyStringUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string MyString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyStringProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyString", typeof(string), typeof(MyStringUserControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

And this ViewModel:

```
public class MyStringViewModel
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Now I use the MyStringUserControl in another View like this:

```
<controls:MyStringUserControl MyString="{Binding SomeStringProperty} />
```

I'am looking for an elegant way to bind this string back to the MyStringViewModel. 
I also don't feel comfortable with the fact that I have to duplicate every property in the UserControl code behind and ViewModel. Is there a better way to do this?

#### Edit #1:

The reason I want to do this is because of unit testing (creating a UserControl takes very long even without InitializeComponent)

Comment: Why do you need a ViewModel on a user control? I cannot remember having had a TextBoxViewModel or a ComboBoxViewModel ever. I'm a big fan of MVVM, but I think a user control is just that... a control. Plain and simple.

Comment: Because of unit testing. If I directly use the UserControl every test takes ~700ms just to create the control.

Comment: For unit-testing, you can skip InitializeComponents() call in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but event without InitializeComponent it still takes ~100ms which is way too long.

Comment: @nvoigt I agree without context it's hard to understand if what NKusperer is doing is appropriate, but I will say that I have on occasion done similar things and I felt they were appropriate then. As an example I have created a LoginViewModel and a LoginView, I made the LoginViewModel internal and set it as the DataContext. This made more sense to me then stuffing everything into CodeBehind and setting the DataContext to self. I was also able to create additional versions of the view(Window, UserControl, Page).

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no point in duplicating your properties. Using MVVM does *not* mean that you need to have a view model for every `UserControl`. When I use a `UserControl` as a *part* of a view, I rarely use a separate view model for it. Sometimes, I'll just use the `DependencyProperty`s in the `UserControl` code behind, while other times I'll just data bind to the parent view model directly. It all depends on what you want to do with the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I was intent on doing this, I would use DependencyProperty's PropertyChanged event handler to set my ViewModel's property, and my ViewModel's PropertyChanged event handler to set my DependencyProperty. Having said that I've never had a reason to go down this particular road.

```
private SomeViewModel _viewModel;

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyString", typeof(string), typeof(MyStringUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(OnMyStringChanged));

public MyStringUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _viewModel = new SomeViewModel();
    _viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;

    this.DataContext = _viewModel;
}

private static void OnMyStringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MyStringUserControl)d).OnMyStringChanged(e.NewValue);
}

private void OnMyStringChanged(string newValue)
{
    _viewModel.SomeProperty = newValue;
}

private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "SomeProperty":
            SetValue(MyStringProperty, _viewModel.SomeProperty);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is very tight coupling.